# Create a meeting on a calendar where people can sign themselves up or request to be invited in Office 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

At my workplace, I organize several classes / events that are open for anyone within my organization to participate. The problem here is that these events often move due to instructor availability.

There are 2 primary problems:

1. As mentioned above, the meetings often move
2. People learn about these meetings randomly so I don't have all the names of people that will be attending before the meetings are created.

What I would like is a way for people to be able to see a common calendar and either "add themselves" or "request to be invited to" a meeting.

Things I have tried:

1. Create the meeting and invite the original list of people.

   1. Problem: Whenever someone decides that they want to go, I have open every single meeting and invite them individually. Total time drain.
2. Send people ICS files so they can copy them to their calendar

   1. Problem: ICS files create a copy of a meeting, so if the original changes time / date, the person who used the ICS file does not get the update. This is also a pain when meetings changes. I used to create a zip with all the ICS files, but they don't update when the meetings changes since they are plain text.
3. (This is where I am now) Use power automate to set up a flow that people fill out a survey that triggers a flow that invites (in reality, forwards the meeting request) the people who want to go. This way, I only share the link to a single survey and they get invited to all the meetings.

   1. Problem: Power automate is very fragile and has a ton of hidden constraints. Also, I have to make 2 flows in order for this to work (there is likely a better way, but after nearly having an aneurysm, I left the 2). The first flow is to get all the meeting request IDs, and the second is the trigger from the flow to forward all the meeting requests. Every time there is a new set of classes, I have to make 2 new flows.

The number of classes / common event is starting to increase and the Power Automate solution isn't scaling well.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: As I know, it's not available in Outlook client. We can only organize meetings by manually adding participants.